# Keep track of multiple checkboxes react

Tags: reactjs

I have several checkboxes that are generated dynamically from an API call and I need to submit all the checked checkboxes back to the API, The checkboxes are in groups and I need to get selected checkboxes for each group, is there a way I can keep track of this using the state?

[image]

In this scenario I need to submit

```
add-on : add-on-1, add-on-2
addd-on : add-on-1
```

API Results

```
{
 "addons": [
  {
   "addonMandatory": false,
   "addons": [
    {
     "name": "add-on-1",
     "price": "10"
    },
    {
     "name": "add-on-2",
     "price": "10"
    },
    {
     "name": "add-on-3",
     "price": "10"
    },
    {
     "name": "add-on-4",
     "price": "10"
    }
   ],
   "maximimCount": "2",
   "name": "add-on"
  },
  {
   "addonMandatory": false,
   "addons": [
    {
     "name": "add-on-1",
     "price": "10"
    },
    {
     "name": "add-on-2",
     "price": "10"
    }
   ],
   "maximimCount": "1",
   "name": "addd-on"
  }
 ],
 "description": "",
 "image": "https://i.imgur.com/qDkhpPa.jpg",
 "name": "Product 7",
 "price": "10"
}
```

Current attempt

```
addAddonToState() {
        var addons = this.props.product.addons
        var addonsGroup = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < addons.length; i++) {
            for (var z = 0; z < addons[i].addons.length; z++) {
                var addonInit = {
                    name: addons[i].addons[z].name,
                    checked: false
                }
                addonsGroup.push(addonInit)
            }
        }
        this.setState({addons: addonsGroup})
    }
```

I can't figure out what to do after this step as I have multiple addons with the same name

Comment: Can you give an example of the data returned from an API call and the code you have already tried?

Comment: @TeymourAldridge sure ill add the data returned and the state that i have so far

Comment: Thanks. This will help to increase the quality of the question and help you to get better answers.

Comment: @TeymourAldridge I updated the question with my current approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
You could implement it by having a function that have as a param the checkbox value.
Then you can setState the value into the state.
Make sure you check if the value arleady is inside , just becuase the way checkboxes work they will trigger the onClick event when clicked on.

```
     addCheckboxesValue = (event) => {
        const {value} = event.target; // The value of the clicked Checkbox 
        const { checkboxesValue } = this.state // The state in our class 
        let updatedCheckboxesValue = [...checkboxesValue] 
        if ( updatedCheckboxesValue.includes(value) ) { 
          updatedCheckboxesValue = updatedCheckboxesValue.filter(checked => checked !== value) 
        } else { 
          updatedCheckboxesValue = [...checkboxesValue, value] 
        } 
        this.setState({checkboxesValue: updatedCheckboxesValue}) 
        console.log(updatedCheckboxesValue)
      }
```

Comment: ~const addCheckboxesValue` = (event) => {
const { value } = even.target;  // The value of the clicked Checkbox
const { checkboxesValue } = this.state // The state in our class
let updatedCheckboxesValue = [...checkboxesValue]
if ( updatedCheckboxesValue.includes(value) ) {
  updatedCheckboxesValue = updatedCheckboxesValue.filter(checkboxV => checkBoxV !== value)
 }
else  {
updatedCheckboxesValue = [...checkboxesValue, value]
}
this.setState({checkboxesValue: updatedCheckboxesValue})
}~

Comment: Sorry, not sure how to make it as a code, will try fix it soon

Comment: @OmerCohen I added the code to the answer, and this actually worked for me! Thanks!!